# How to find files based on other files in current directory, with find command?

Tags: find

Want to find all mkv files without having same-name ass/srt file in the same folder.

How can I do that?

for example, I have following directory:

```
folder_1
|----folder_2
|      |-----a.mkv
|      |-----a.srt
|----folder_3
|      |-----b.mkv
|----folder_4
       |-----c.mkv
       |-----c.ass
```

The search result should be: folder_1/folder_3/b.mkv.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get answer from my friends, share it:

```
find . -name "*.mkv" -o -name "*.ass" -o -name "*.srt"| sort |rev|uniq -s 3 -u| rev|rgrep ".mkv"
```

BTW, if you are using synology nas, which does not have 'rev' command, you can walkaround it by using a python script(rev.py):

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
        if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
                for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
                        print '"' + arg[::-1] + '"'
```

and the script will be changed to:

```
find . -name "*.mkv" -o -name "*.ass" -o -name "*.srt"| sort |awk '{print "\"", $0,"\""}' OFS=""|xargs python rev.py |uniq -s 3 -u| xargs python rev.py | grep ".mkv\""
```